# Enable mono-audio only when one earbud is connected?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, settings, accessibility

I have mono audio enabled in accessibility on my iPhone because most of the time, I'm only using a single earbud, and don't want that to impact what I hear.

That being said, from time to time I will use both of my earbuds, and go into settings to disable/re-enable mono audio manually.

Is there a way to have it automatically enable if I'm only using one earbud? Does the device actually know if I'm using one earbud or two?